# JPA / Hibernate: StringClobType deprecated

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I recently upgraded Spring Boot and with this came a hibernate upgrade. Unfortunately, the entity column `@Type(StringClobType)` annotation has been deprecated. The documentation tell me I need to switch it to `MaterilizedClobType`.

Unfortunately this has broken my application.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5. The `StringClobType` annotation created a `text` type in the database which allowed me to store long text in the field. Unfortunately now, the string literal comes back when Hibernate is expecting some kind of LOB id.

This gives the error: `Bad value for type long`

Comment: Postgres does a poor job of documenting how its extension data types such a `text` map to JDBC, but it looks and sounds as if `org.hibernate.type.TextType` would be a likely choice for mapping a column of type `text`.  Hibernate says it maps to JDBC's `LONGVARCHAR` type. It's not clear that the characteristics of that type exactly match PG's `Text`, but they seem close.

Comment: you could just mention **@Lob** annotation above your member variable. while persisting the objects into the database, Hibernate automatically takes CLOB for a String if it is exceeding its limit and takes the input as **text** in the database.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, you hit the nail on the head. Thank you! Please add this an an legit answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hibernate `@Type` value that maps to PG's `Text` data type is `org.hibernate.type.TextType`.  This is what you should use.

For what it's worth, this a sibling of `org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType`, which maps to `CLOB`; both are subclasses of `org.hibernate.type.AbstractLongStringType`.